# How to list all events bound to a widget in tkinter & how to list their handlers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

If others have different solutions or actual documentation, I would love to see it. To my knowledge this is undocumented, so I'm adding a bit to the stack overflow knowledgebase on tkinter:

To list events bound to a widget:

Use the bind() method with no arguments.

```
listbox_main.bind()
```

which returns a tuple containing the text string(s) of those event(s) bound to the widget.

```
('<<ListboxSelect>>',)
```

Then to list the handler(s) for said events, call bind with the name of the event you wish to inspect:

```
listbox_main.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>')
```

Which returns:

```
if {"[22994296selection_handler %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break
```

Which appears to be a text string of the tcl command that would be executed when this event is fired and the handler is called (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm no tcl expert). Where the name of my handler is "selection_handler".

I encourage anyone with additional information to post here, I will upvote and mark as correct the answer that links to documentation or the most supporting evidence; Also any suggestions of tags to add to the post to help it sift to the top of Google searches.

I hope that helps at least one person from digging through dir() like I had to. =P

Comment: Are you asking a question, or just providing information?

Comment: @BryanOakley Just providing information. I know when I have a problem the stacks are my first stop, so I thought this might be the best place.

Comment: You should phrase this as a question, and then put the information in an answer.